# how to check schema registry cluster and how to set cluster mode using docker compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-schema-registry

I made a docker-compose file to setup Kafka and schema registry.
but I can't check if schema registry cluster is working well.

How to check schema registry cluster mode?

Is my docker-compose file working well as cluster? I'm not sure it works well.
I only can see that two Kafka and two registry running.

here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.7.0
    container_name: zookeeper-ri
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
    container_name: kafka-1
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka1:19091, EXTERNAL://:9091"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka1:19091, EXTERNAL://localhost:9091"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT, EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
  kafka2:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
      container_name: kafka-2
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 2
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka2:19092, EXTERNAL://:9092"
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "INTERNAL://kafka2:19092, EXTERNAL://localhost:9092"
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT, EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
  
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: kafka-ui
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
      - zookeeper
      - schema-registry1
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka1:19091, kafka2:19092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_SCHEMAREGISTRY=http://schema-registry1:8085,http://schema-registry2:8086

  schema-registry1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    restart: always
    container_name: registry-1
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry-1
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8085
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19091,PLAINTEXT://kafka2:19092
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  schema-registry2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    restart: always
    container_name: registry-2
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - kafka2
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry-2
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8086
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19091,PLAINTEXT://kafka2:19092

    ports:
      - 8086:8086
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one schema registry instance can operate on the _schemas topic at any time. So, you can start a consumer for that topic, then try to register two separate schemas, but one to each instance of the registry. If one fails but the other succeeds, then you have a leader election problem

You might want to look at the `master.eligibility` config option, for example